# AWS Opsworks Java App Server 403 Error

Tags: java, jsp, aws-opsworks

I am a newbie to AWS Opsworks. I am trying to deploy the simplest of AWS Opsworks Application using Java App Server, by following this: http://java.awsblog.com/post/Tx1QG3W2M969014/AWS-OpsWorks-for-Java

I did everything as mentioned but when I deploy and try to view the URL, it says:
**Forbidden
You don't have permission to access /JavaBasic/HelloWorldService.jsp on this server.**

Can someone guide me to how I should resolve this?

Comment: I have met the same problem too!

Comment: Anan, @KitHo Does my answer work? I'm not certain if it will, but without more information it's the best I can do.

Comment: Anyone there? Have you tested my answer? Does it work? I really want to know because it's been a while since I've used Apache, and if I still remember anything I'm gonna be happy

Comment: @QPaysTaxes it doesn't work, looks like default apache config vhost problem

Comment: @KitHo I've looked around a good bit more over the past couple of days and haven't found anything. As a last-ditch effort, have you tried turning it off, then back on? That is, after using `chmod` did you reboot Apache? If you did and it still didn't work, I have no idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I remember seeing in the Apache documentation, you need to change the permissions for the file, so everyone -- even not-logged-in users -- can see it. That way, you can access it through a browser, since that's a loginless connection.

The following command should do the trick:

```
sudo chmod -R  755 /path/to/www
```

Where `/path/to/www` is the absolute path, from the root, to the topmost directory of the files on the website. Using Apache2, it seems like it'll be `/var/www`, though it may be different for you.

Note that you'll have to have the password for the root account for `sudo` to work; if you don't, try it without and it might still.

EDIT: After a good bit of research, I determined that you only need to give the `www-data` user permission to see the pages, since that's what Apache uses. Setting the permission to `755` will do this, but any solution that gives `www-data` the ability to read the file will do the same thing. For example, this would also work, assuming Apache uses `www-data`:

```
sudo chown -R www-data /path/to/www
```

Again, `/path/to/www` should be the absolute path to the root of your website, and you'll need the password for the `root` account.

Comment: this is usually the issue if a webserver is sending a 403 when it shouldn't be. Honestly this is less an issue with jsp and moreso a systems administration / filesystem permissions issue

Comment: @zack6849 That's what I was thinking, too. It's why my answer is about permissions, not debugging java code.

Comment: It is basically path issues. @QPaysTaxes, I had stumbled on the same solution! The way to resolve this was to actually be able to login as root or know exactly what relative path will help to actually open the App.